# Find value in a array of Structure

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to find the value of a Struture which is contained inside an Array. The following diagram shows the representation:

[image: How the Structure is looking to find a value]

I tried the code below, but it is giving me this error, using CF 9.0.1

```
Element OPTIONTYPE_NAME is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression.
```

Code I am trying:

```
<cfif !ArrayIsEmpty(result)>
    <cfset arrayIndex = 0>
    <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(result)#" index="counter">
        <cfif result[counter].OPTIONTYPE_NAME IS "color">
            <cfset arrayIndex = counter>
            <cfdump var="#arrayIndex#">
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the error is pretty much telling you what the problem is. There *isn't* a key `OPTIONTYPE_NAME` in `result[counter]`.

`result[counter]` has keys `key`, `owner` and `path`.

I think you want to be looking at `result[counter].owner.OPTIONTYPE_NAME`

Comment: Thanks, it worked, Now i have added one more condition to fetch the value of the structure if needed with following : `code`<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(result)#" index="counter">
    <cfif result[counter].owner.OPTIONTYPE_NAME IS "color">
        <cfset arrayIndex = evaluate(result[counter].owner.OPTIONTYPE_ID)>
        <cfdump var="#arrayIndex#">
    </cfif>
</cfloop>`code`

Comment: Misty, you don't need evaluate there. (In general, the situations where evaluate is necessary are rare.)  Also use just backticks  to markup code in comments. i.e. `<cfloop...` is ` <cfloop... ` (without spaces).

Comment: Thanks Peter for letting know these details